# HttpGet response 200 returns with fallback page

Tags: cors, httpclient, identityserver4

I have been working on a webapp webapi project and hosted blazor WASM oidc client. The webapi HttpGet is returning the json response when debuging on localhost.  I have worked on all headers, cors, oidc, redirect urls necessary to get a stable oidc server in a separate domain.

The problem is in production to azure webapp the same webapi HttpGet is always returning the html fallback page text html and not the json result.   I wonder if my authorization needs to be enhanced since localhost may have relaxed rules than running in azure production.

Note - only one call to openid configuration fails in the entire session which seems to be cancellation from authentication service after the call to the razor page containing the call to HttpGet (possible it was checking authorization on logged in user)?

I have used web application logging in the portal which seems to indicate the same as the network tab of developer tab.

[browser tools network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcmTI.png)

My thought is a cors issue since all client/api code works localhost to identity server in different domain as mentioned. In production on azure the cors settings do not set the correct websockets (because they are unknown?) only the domains. The responses  from the client to the webapi seem to function as same-origin as seen in browser developer networking tab.

Please ask for code samples so that the relevant snippets are sent.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a work in progress ;however, this is not a CORS issue. The correct html request headers and CORS settings are in project(s). Just to have a sense of closure restarted with a small project that allows the controller to be tested in production environment. The original project was using html client which was not be saving settings throughout project moving to IHttpClient factory implementation.  Please mark the CORS issue as closed. Best Regards.